# Android Debug Monitor - Pause Logging

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

Trying to debug my app, and the constant stream from logcat first makes it hard to stay put (the scroll lock issue), and then overwrites everything. Is there a way to pause LogCat? Currently resorting to unplugging the cable, and stopping the log that way.

Answers that use something other than ADM are nice, but I want something I can do from ADM.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, un-selecting the most-right button should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: I would also add that you should look at learning to use the filters so that you can pare the amount of data down a bit. Also helpful is to set break points in your code and then using step [into|over|out] to really get a good idea of what is happening in a particularly problematic section of code.

Comment: Isn't that scroll-lock? AFAIK, that doesn't pause the log, it just does thing so the scrolling of it, although I'm not to clear on what, exactly.

And I'm not in Eclipse, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to clear the logcat

```
adb logcat -C
```

Comment: Again, while I thank you, this doesn't do what I want. I do not want to clear the log, I want to pause it.